# making multiple choice with data from database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to make a multiple choice and the question is coming from database. I am sure that my database name is correct, but when i click **next**, the question is not changing, it is directly going to the end/result of question and the question is not random too. The last question that I inserted into the database is displayed in webpage. Please help

this is my code:

```
<?php
require_once('includes/db_conn.php');
$query = "select * from question";
$query_result = $dbc->query($query);
$num_questions_returned = $query_result->num_rows;

if ($num_questions_returned < 1){
    echo "There is no question in the database";
    exit();}
$questionsArray = array();
while ($row = $query_result->fetch_assoc()){
    $questionsArray[] = $row;
}

$correctAnswerArray = array();
foreach($questionsArray as  $question){
    $correctAnswerArray[$question['question']] = $question['correct_answer'];
}

$questions = array();
foreach($questionsArray as $question) {
    $questions[$question['question']] = $question['question'];
 }

$choices = array();
foreach ($questionsArray as $row) {
    $choices[$row['question']] = array($row['wrong_answer1'], $row['wrong_answer2'], $row['wrong_answer3'], $row['correct_answer']);
  }

error_reporting(0);
$address = "";
$randomizequestions ="yes";

$a = array(
1 => array(
   0 => $question['question'],
   1 => $row['wrong_answer1'],
   2 => $row['wrong_answer2'],
   3 => $row['wrong_answer3'],
   4 => $row['correct_answer'],
   6 => 4
),
);

$max=1;

$question=$_POST["question"] ;

if ($_POST["Randon"]==0){
        if($randomizequestions =="yes"){$randval = mt_rand(1,$max);}else{$randval=1;}
        $randval2 = $randval;
        }else{
        $randval=$_POST["Randon"];
        $randval2=$_POST["Randon"] + $question;
                if ($randval2>$max){
                $randval2=$randval2-$max;
                }
        }

$ok=$_POST["ok"] ;

if ($question==0){
        $question=0;
        $ok=0;
        $percentage=0;
        }else{
        $percentage= Round(100*$ok / $question);
        }
?>

<HTML><HEAD>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
<!-- 
function Goahead (number){
        if (document.percentaje.response.value==0){
                if (number==<?php print $a[$randval2][6] ; ?>){
                        document.percentaje.response.value=1
                        document.percentaje.question.value++
                        document.percentaje.ok.value++
                }else{
                        document.percentaje.response.value=1
                        document.percentaje.question.value++
                }
        }
        if (number==<?php print $a[$randval2][6] ; ?>){
                document.question.response.value="Correct"
        }else{
                document.question.response.value="Incorrect"
        }
}
// -->
</SCRIPT>

</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR=FFFFFF>

<CENTER>
<H1><?php print "$title"; ?></H1>
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=5 WIDTH=500>

<?php if ($question<$max){ ?>

<TR><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>
<FORM METHOD=POST NAME="percentaje" ACTION="<?php print $URL; ?>">

<BR>Percentaje of correct responses: <?php print $percentage; ?> %
<BR><input type=submit value="Next >>">
<input type=hidden name=response value=0>
<input type=hidden name=question value=<?php print $question; ?>>
<input type=hidden name=ok value=<?php print $ok; ?>>
<input type=hidden name=Randon value=<?php print $randval; ?>>
<br><?php print $question+1; ?> / <?php print $max; ?>
</FORM>
<HR>
</TD></TR>

<TR><TD>
<FORM METHOD=POST NAME="question" ACTION="">
<?php print "<b>".$a[$randval2][0]."</b>"; ?>

<BR>     <INPUT TYPE=radio NAME="option" VALUE="1"  onClick=" Goahead (1);"><?php print $a[$randval2][1] ; ?>
<BR>     <INPUT TYPE=radio NAME="option" VALUE="2"  onClick=" Goahead (2);"><?php print $a[$randval2][2] ; ?>
<?php if ($a[$randval2][3]!=""){ ?>
<BR>     <INPUT TYPE=radio NAME="option" VALUE="3"  onClick=" Goahead (3);"><?php print $a[$randval2][3] ; } ?>
<?php if ($a[$randval2][4]!=""){ ?>
<BR>     <INPUT TYPE=radio NAME="option" VALUE="4"  onClick=" Goahead (4);"><?php print $a[$randval2][4] ; } ?>

<BR>     <input type=text name=response size=8>


</FORM>

<?php
}else{
?>
<TR><TD ALIGN=Center>
The Quiz has finished
<BR>Percentage of correct responses: <?php print $percentage ; ?> %
<p><A HREF="<?php print $address; ?>">Home Page</a>

<?php } ?>

</TD></TR>
</TABLE>

</CENTER>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

this is my process add data to database:

```
<?php
include('includes/header.html');

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

//Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['question'])||
    empty($_POST['correct_answer']) ||
    empty($_POST['wrong_answer1'])      ||
    empty($_POST['wrong_answer2'])      ||
    empty($_POST['wrong_answer3']))
{
    echo "Please complete all fields";
    exit();
}

//Create short variables
$question = $_POST['question'];
$correct_answer = ($_POST['correct_answer']);
$wrong_answer1 = ($_POST['wrong_answer1']);
$wrong_answer2 = ($_POST['wrong_answer2']);
$wrong_answer3 = ($_POST['wrong_answer3']);

//connect to the database
require_once('includes/db_conn.php');

//Create the insert query
$query = "INSERT INTO question VALUES ('$question', '$correct_answer', '$wrong_answer1','$wrong_answer2','$wrong_answer3')";

$result = $dbc->query($query);

if($result){
    echo "Your quiz has been saved";
} else {
    echo '<h1>System Error</h1>';
}
$dbc->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first mistake is making array of $a why are you not using $choices which you had made in last for loop and for random questions handle $choices array and your submit button of next is outside the form so you will not get form values on next button.take it inside the form tag.

Another thing is on radio button click don't write anything just write your function on submit click event and then handle the next question after saving the previous answer.

These are what my suggestions.. for more help put here your database back up and its connected files so that I can help you in coding.